# Julia 1.6.1. not start on Windows

Tags: julia

I downloaded and installed the latest version of Julia 1.6.1 x64, operating system is Windows 10 x64 with all updates. However, the installed julia.exe it doesn't start. It looks as if a window opens for a moment and closes at the same moment. The new process does not start. I downloaded the portable version of Julia 1.6.1 - there is the same result. At the same time, the version of Julia 1.5.3 works fine. I assumed that the problem might be some incompatible data inside the directory .julia and tried to temporarily rename it so that Julia started as a clean slate, but the result is still the same: Julia 1.6.1 does not start, Julia 1.5.3 starts normally (and creates an empty directory .julia). Previously, such problems with updates have never been observed. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Open command line (rtpe  `cmd` in start menu), run your `julia.exe` from then and write what happens

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea of running from the command line, I didn't think about this feature myself. I launched julia.exe from the command line and got the error:

```
ERROR: could not load library "C:\Program Files\Julia 1.5.3\lib\julia\sys.dll"
The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Obviously, since at startup Julia is looking for a library from a different version, I had some environment variables set that I forgot to change. I changed the path in them to the path to the new version and after that everything worked. But although the problem seems to be solved at the moment, it doesn't seem obvious to me why the path from the environment variable has a higher priority than the path to the file in the installation directory. Potentially because of this, there may be problems when trying to share two versions. As far as I can remember, I was creating these environment variables to run Julia from R. Now all that code, until I make changes to it that are necessary to switch to the new version, may stop working.